# Redshift vacuum progress in console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Is there a way to observe `VACUUM` progress and related stats in AWS Console?

I know that there are few tables that I could query, e.g. `SVV_VACUUM_PROGRESS` or `STL_VACUUM`, but it would be nice to see these metrics in dashboard/console.

Answer (score 0):

Form the AWS console you can see this from Queries tab of redshift cluster.

[image]